# ES6: How to use await with callbacks

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, async-await, es6-promise

Here is the wrapper for `vue-router` written on TypeScript:

```js
abstract class RoutingHelper {

  // ...

  public static redirectToNamedRoute(targetRouteName: AnyValueOf<typeof NamedRoutes>): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve: () => void): void => {
      router.push({ name: targetRouteName }, resolve);
    });
  }
}
```

The rule [@typescript-eslint/promise-function-async](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/promise-function-async.md) forces that method which returns `Promise` will be `async`:

```js
public static async redirectToNamedRoute(targetRouteName: AnyValueOf<typeof NamedRoutes>): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve: () => void): void => {
      router.push({ name: targetRouteName }, resolve);
    });
  }
```

Now [require-await](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/require-await) tells me that method must include `await` keyword. How I can observe `require-await` in this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 return await new Promise<...>(...);
```

will make the linter happy. But honestly, there is no sense in enforcing that rule here. It only makes sense to await a promise if you want to work with the promises result before returning.

Comment: Or just remove the async keyword

Comment: @BalintCsak, thank you for the comment! What about [promise-function-async](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/promise-function-async.md) rule?

Comment: @JonasWilms, thank you for the answer. I see, so breaking the rule `require-await` is not violating ES6, is not it?

Comment: No it isn't. Linter rules are there to write best practice code in *the general case*, not in *all cases*

Comment: @BalintCsak both aren't mandatory here, but both are required by the linters.